# What copper tube adaptor is this?

Tags: water-heater

This is from a tankless water heater with about 1/4" copper tube. Is the adaptor standard (encircled in blue)? What type is it?

[image]

Comment: I've not seen anything like this.  What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Looks like a proprietary connector selected by the mfgr to connect to another fitting which does have a standard connection point.

Comment: I want to add a new flow switch.

Comment: I believe it is an OEM compression fitting for high temp.